# Does reloadItems(at:) reloads constraints and other collectionView items

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

I would like to as you about function `reloadItems(at:)` and generally about reloading `constraints` in cell. In my case I would like to update my last cell in UICollectionView. When updating this cell I would like to also update its height. And here is place where I'm confused. Does `reloadItems(at:)` updates constraints of this cell? I can set manually some height to my last cell, then call `reloadItems(at:)` and will `constraints` of this cell change or do I have to do it on my own? Will this affect to other `UICollectionView` cells if I change height for only one cell? Did they shrink or something? Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: You gotta try it. But in all essence it should!

Comment: you cannot ask for layout change in reloaditem, reload item is specific for reloading the item and not the layout, you use viewlayoutsubviews to change the layout